# What's the use of the underscore in Clojure's let binding form?

Tags: clojure

What does an underscore within the binding vector of a let do, so if i write `(let [a blabla _ (println a)] etc....`
what is this underline doing at the place of the keyword?

Comment: here is a more conceret example: `user=> (let [a (take 5 (range))
             {:keys [b c d] :or {d 10 b 20 c 30}} {:c 50 :d 100}
             [e f g & h] ["a" "b" "c" "d" "e"]
             _ (println "I was here!")
             foo 12
             bar (+ foo 100)]
         [a b c d e f g h foo bar])
I was here!
[(0 1 2 3 4) 20 50 100 "a" "b" "c" ("d" "e") 12 112]`

Answer (score 14):

The underscore is a valid symbol identifier, as you can see by this sample code:

```
(let [_ 1] 
  (println _))
=> 1
```

By convention when you have an identifier you won't be using you *may* use `_`, but it's not mandatory.

Happens both for side effect situations as in your sample (in your case the `println` line returns `nil` so you won't be binding its result to a symbol)

Happens also on destructuring situations where you don't need some of the values.

```
 (let [[a _ _ d] [1 2 3 4]] 
    (println a))
 => 1
```

In this case you're not interested in 2nd and 3rd values, so the identifier `_` is idiomatic for saying you don't care.

In regular Clojure the underscore `_` is treated like any other symbol (e.g. "junk").  However it has a special meaning in some libraries.  For example, in Datomic the `_` is treated like a "wildcard" that prevents binding/unification.  In clojure.core.match, the `_` is also treated as a wildcard.

See:

- [Datomic Query](http://docs.datomic.com/query.html#blanks)
- [clojure.core.match](https://github.com/clojure/core.match)

Comment: great, thank you. So is it only for the sake of space-filling and debugging?

Comment: I guess you can say so

Answer (score 4):

The underscore is the universal ignore symbol.

There has to be a return value for each sexp in the let form, and `println` returns nil, so you can set it to `_` to tell people you are ignoring the return and just doing debug at that point. e.g.

```
(let [foo (+ 1 2)
      _   (println "debug! foo is" foo)
      _   (println "more debug!" (+ 1 foo)]
  foo)
```

each evaluation of the sexp sets the `_` to the value returned, but it's not required, so just read it as such.

Comment: great, thank you. So is it only for the sake of space-filling and debugging? –

Comment: Yes, just side effects

Comment: A note on terminology: _ is not a value, it's a symbol. (class (quote _)) returns clojure.lang.Symbol Symbols have to be quoted or they get eVALUEated (class _) will return the class of the value that underscore is currently bound to.

Comment: Semi-OT, is the word "sexp" still appropriate? The traditional list of cons elements is gone, so instead of [s-expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S-expression), now a historical term, just "expression" might be better. ("The Joy of Clojure" uses that term only once, apparently the author fell back to old habits)